# JQuery button to disable CSS across entire website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I want to make these buttons which enable/disable the css across an entire website I am making. I am trying to make it so when a user clicks the button to disable/enable the css, it does so across all the webpages of the site and not just for the page a user is on.

So far, my code to enable/disable the css is as follows

```
<script>
$("#text-only").click(function () { jQuery('#mainStyleSheet').remove();}); 
$("#renable-style").click(function () {$('head').append('<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" id="mainStyleSheet" />');});
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't think you can do it like that unless it's a single page application. What you'd probably need to do is fire off an AJAX request to set a global variable on the server and only output the link tag when it's not false, and of course use JS to remove it from the current page.

Comment: research `cookies` or `localStorage` to store and retrieve the current "state" - so that navigating to new pages can enable/disable the CSS as appropriate.

Comment: Maybe save a temporary file or cookie that tells if style is enabled or disabled so you can check the cookie when you load the new web pages

Answer (score 0):

```
{$('head').append('<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" id="mainStyleSheet" />');});
```

instead of

```
{$('head').html('<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" id="mainStyleSheet" />');});
```

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you should add a css class to every object that you have made in the webpage.In that class make all the changes.